# Converting northing/westing coordinates into decimal values

Tags: java, geolocation, location

I am writing a class which performs convertion of **northing/westing** cooordinates into **longitude/latitude** values. I use the `JCoord` library for that.

The init happens here:

```
public ConverterImpl(double northing, double westing) throws IllegalArgumentException {
   double easting = 360 - westing;
   ll = new OSRef(easting, northing).toLatLng();
   ll.toWGS84();
}
```

Now the following are the northing/westing coordinates:

- "53 59.655N","001 32.300W"

As you can see, it's not in decimal format, when the `OSRef` class takes `double` values. That is where the problem lies.

How to convert the above northing/westing coordinates into decimal format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have resolved my problem.
In short, what I wanted, in the end, is the **latitude** and **longitude** coordinates from the coordinates which come like in the following example:

- "53 59.655N","001 32.300W"

It can be calculated in the following way:

- Longitude: -(1 + 32.300/60), in this case, needs to be negative
- Latitude: 53 + 59.655/60